# How to cast object to type known only at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

Consider the following situation. I have a `Dictionary<string,string> dictionary`, and a `string key`. I do not know these two types at compile time, but I do know them at runtime. So at compile time, they're just objects. I'd like to make the call dictionary.ContainsKey(key). However, because key is a string "cast to an object", this yields a RuntimeBinderException. I'd like to understand how to resolve this issue.

Here are some tests demonstrating the issue:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ThisTestFails()
    {
        dynamic dictionary = getDict();
        var key = getKey();

        bool result = dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ThisTestWorks()
    {
        dynamic dictionary = getDict();
        var key = (string)getKey();

        bool result = dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    private object getDict() => new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "abc", "def" } };
    private object getKey() => "abc";
```

`ThisTestFails` fails with a `RunTimeBinderException`, while `ThisTestWorks` passes. So, what's happening is that while the `key` variable in both tests contains a string, its apparent type in `ThisTestFails` is an object, which can't be used in `dictionary.ContainsKey`.

What I need to resolve this, essentially, is a way to "cast" the `key` variable to a string at runtime. The `(string)key` solution in `ThisTestWorks` won't be useful to me, as I in the general case don't know the type of the dictionary key at compile time. What can be done to solve the issue?

Comment: Why is the dictionary using `string` typed keys, when the actual type of the keys is not known at compile time? Have you considered to simply use the `object` type as key? When the keys of your dictionary can be "any type of object", then IMHO it makes more sense to use the `object` type for representing the key (instead of using a text).

Comment: Well, the string keys and values are just examples. In reality, the dictionary is found by reflection and has generic type parameters which are quite sensible, but are just not known at runtime by the client, because the dictionary could be from a property on quite a few different classes. So there's good reason for not having object as the key type.

Comment: This might be an XY problem, so perhaps you might benefit from sharing the actual problem you are trying to solve. In many cases, `dynamic` can be avoided in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think You are looking for something like this

```
dynamic dictionary = getDict();
dynamic key = getKey();

bool result = (bool)dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

But here might be another problem because You are trying to look for a string which is boxed in 'object' type(this type is returned from your methods like GetKey()) so in containKey method comparison will be done as for object type meaning by reference not by value as for string.

Comment: Are you sure `string`s are boxed?

Comment: Hi @C.Evenhuis, getKey returns 'object' so I'm quite sure it will be boxed, however I didn't test it